# Capslock (and other keys) indicator for Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell, capslock

I know there are many solutions to this problem like using `indicator-keylock` or using `lks-indicator`.

I have tried them both. However since I am on Ubuntu 18.04, these are not working.

Can someone help me with something new or help me in writing a new indicator which I can use for myself at least?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use one of the following [GNOME shell extensions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) to achieve your goal.

- [Lock Keys](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/)
  This extension shows <kbd>Num lock</kbd> or <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> (or both) status on the top bar.
  [image]
- [Keys Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1105/keys-indicator/)
  This extension shows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Num lock</kbd>, and <kbd>Caps lock</kbd> status on the top bar.
  [image]
- [Lock Keys](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1532/lock-keys/) (another one)
  Numlock & Capslock status on the panel. Icons are auto hidden. Simplified with no menus, notifications or settings.

Comment: is there a way to launch the indicator before login? When the login password must be entered?

Comment: @gospes Most probably not *these ones* because as per GNOMe's security policy extensions do not work even in lock screens.

Answer (score 4):

There's a ppa for indicator-keylock on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tsbarnes/indicator-keylock
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-keylock
```